# In Batch how do I take a list of IPs converted to hex and output them to a file as decimal?

Tags: batch-file

I've found a way online to take a user input hex figure and convert it to decimal but I'd like to add to it by passing a list of hex IPs (one on each line, in the short format of E00000FC, for example) and having the conversions input to another file in the same format.

So far I have:

```
SETLOCAL
set /a dec=0x%~1
( ENDLOCAL & REM RETURN VALUES
    IF "%~2" NEQ "" (SET %~2=%dec%) ELSE ECHO.%dec% > dec_list.txt
)
EXIT /b
```

I tried to add:

```
FOR /F "eol= delims=, " %i in (hex_list.txt) do
```

After the 'SETLOCAL' to no avail.

Also, I guess I'm going to have problems with the conversion totalling the number instead of outputting four octets. Would passing two hex values at a time be the best way to aviod this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set hex=%%a
   set "dec="
   for /L %%i in (0,2,6) do (
      set /A num=0x!hex:~%%i,2!
      set dec=!dec!.!num!
   )
   echo !dec:~1!
)) > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it in pure batch

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%a in (hexips.txt) do (
   set "hexip=%%a"
   call :convert 
)
exit /b

:convert
set first=%hexip:~0,2%
set second=%hexip:~2,2%
set third=%hexip:~4,2%
set fourth=%hexip:~6,2%
set /a oct1=0x%first%
set /a oct2=0x%second%
set /a oct3=0x%third%
set /a oct4=0x%fourth%
echo %oct1%.%oct2%.%oct3%.%oct4%>>newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful, but I do each octet separately from powershell.

```
$Octet1 = "{0:D}" -f 0xE0
$Octet2 = "{0:D}" -f 0x00
$Octet3 = "{0:D}" -f 0x00
$Octet4 = "{0:D}" -f 0xFC
$IPAddress = $Octet1 +"."+ $Octet2 +"."+ $Octet3 +"."+ $Octet4
$IPAddress
```

Result

```
224.0.0.252
```

I guess it can be done from batch like this.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
start /b /wait powershell.exe -command "$Octet1 = '{0:D}' -f 0xE0;$Octet2 = '{0:D}' -f 0x00;$Octet3 = '{0:D}' -f 0x00;$Octet4 = '{0:D}' -f 0xFC;$IPAddress = $Octet1 +'.'+ $Octet2 +'.'+ $Octet3 +'.'+ $Octet4;$IPAddress;"
PAUSE
```

Here is a start on one that reads from a .txt file.  I'll get some more time later to look into it.  This splits the hex into 4 octets, just need a full rewrite of the $octet stuff above to work with the pipeline object instead.

```
$i = 0
$lines = Get-Content "B:\File1.txt"
foreach ($line in $lines) {
$line -split '([a-f0-9]{2})'| foreach-object { if ($_) {[System.Convert]::ToByte($_,16)}}
$i++
}
```

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. How would I go about using a list of hex IPs as an input for this statement, rather than hardcoding a single one?